# BigQuery "exceeded quota for queries per day" despite Quota summary says Remaining 100% of total?

Tags: google-bigquery, quota, google-console-developer

During execution of `BigQuery` APIs call we get the exception below:

```
Error while checking Result BigQuery DAO {
  "location" : "query_job",
  "message" : "Quota exceeded: Your project exceed quota for queries per day. 
     For more information see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
  "reason" : "quota exceeded" }
```

We were surprised and checked our quotas in the developers console at https://console.developers.google.com/project/1036887365938/apiui/apiview/bigquery/quotas

There we found under "Quota summary" / Remaining 2,000,000 requests / day, i.e. 
100 % of total.

So everything should be fine. What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to raise Google Big Query daily query quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228593/how-to-raise-google-big-query-daily-query-quota)

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have reached the daily limit for Load Jobs. When does the quota reset back to 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781712/bigquery-i-have-reached-the-daily-limit-for-load-jobs-when-does-the-quota-rese)

Answer (score 1):

The "quota summary" in the google developers console is actually measuring something meaningless; it is the number of all API requests, not queries. We've got an internal bug to suppress those values (they were suppressed at one point, and they resurfaced after the developers console was rewritten).

The quota you're hitting is the number of queries per day. We just doubled the limit to 40k/day (as of 5/27/2015), since it sounds like this has been painful for a number of people. If you need more than that, please follow the instructions in the linked question that Pentium10 pointed you to.